# Reparametrization of regular curve is regular (with slightly different definitions)

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, continuity, curves

When studying some basic differential geometry, I had to prove the following statement:

**If two curves $\alpha: I_\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta :I_\beta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ *determine the same route*** **($\alpha \sim \beta$ ) and $\alpha$ is regular, then $\beta$ is regular.**

However, the definitions and conventions my course notes uses are somewhat different than what I find online. We say that two differentiable curves $\alpha: I_\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta :I_\beta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ *determine the same route* ($\alpha \sim \beta$) if there exists a differentiable bijection $f:I_\alpha \rightarrow I_\beta $ such that $\forall t \in I_\alpha:f'(t) > 0$, and such that $\alpha = \beta \ \circ \ f$. Then $\beta$ is also called a *reparametrization* of $\alpha$.

Also, by *regular* we mean a curve $\alpha$ that is of class $C^1$ (so differentiable and $\alpha'$ continuous ) and $\forall t \in I_\alpha: \alpha'(t) \neq 0$.

I have already shown that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, and the only non trivial part there was the symmetry property.To prove that property I needed two conditions on the differentiable bijection  $f$:

1. $\forall t \in I_\alpha: f'(t) \neq 0$
2. $f^{-1}$ is continuous

The first condition is conveniently given by the definition of $\sim$. However, a continuous bijection does not need to have a continuous inverse. But despite that fact, in this case, it **will** be true that $f^{-1}$ is continuous because $I_\alpha$ is given to be an open interval (this I have shown by using the intermediate value theorem).

So because these two conditions are fullfilled I know that $(f^{-1})'(t) = 1/f'(f^{-1}(t))$.

Now, in order to prove the above statement, I began by using the chain rule:

\begin{align}
\alpha = \beta \circ f &\Rightarrow \beta = \alpha \circ f^{-1} \\
 & \Rightarrow \forall t \in I_\beta: \beta'(t) = \frac{\alpha'(f^{-1}(t))}{f'(f^{-1}(t))}
\end{align}
Now since $\alpha$ is regular, I know that $\alpha'$ is continuous. If I can show that $f'$ is also continuous, I am done. I know that the derivative of a function will not be continuous in general, but my intuition says that in this case it will be true. It will probably have something to do with the fact that $f$ is a bijection on an open interval, just like the same reasoning I used for the inverse. However, I could not find an analogous reasoning for this exercise.

One last thing: I find it quite odd that for the proof that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation I had to come up with a rather non trivial way of showing that $f^{-1}$ is continuous. It feels like I am missing some crucial elements of the theory, with the result being that my proofs are rather long. These exercises were meant as an introduction to differential geometry, so I don't think they are meant to be this long.

Comment: Are you sure that your differentiable bijection $f: I_\alpha\to I_\beta$ doesn't mean $C^1$ bijection? When doing differential geometry, people usually go to $C^\infty$ if needed very quickly. Also the inverse of a bijective continuous function on an open interval is continuous, is a pretty standard fact. Not very easy to prove, but standard. If things are $C^1$, then these all follow from the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @Threeaggies Yes only differentiable bijection, otherwise the exercise will be too trivial I suppose.  I also found it somewhat odd because in another book (not my course notes) they  define a curve as an infinitely differentiable map from an open interval to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then everything becomes way easier. But isn't the statement "the derivative of a differentiable bijection on an open interval is continuous" also true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good question whether a differentiable bijection $f: I_\alpha\to I_\beta$ with $f'(x)>0$, where $I_\alpha$ and $I_\beta$ are open intervals in ${\mathbb R}$, would automatically imply that $f'$ is continuous.

I back-engineered this and found the following counter-example.
$$
f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
3x+x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} & x\in (-1, 0)\cup (0, 1),\\
0 & x=0. 
\end{cases}
$$

We can directly compute that $f'(0) = 3$ from the  definition of derivative. Also for $x\neq 0$, $f'(x)=3+2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}>3-2-1=0$ and we have a strict inequality since $|x|<1$. Therefore $f$ is differentiable, strictly increasing, and maps $(-1,1)$ bijectively to its image $(f(-1), f(1))$.

But $f'$ is not a continuous function, because of the  $-\cos\frac{1}{x}$ term.

(Yes, it is still true that $f^{-1}$ is continuous and differentiable.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this counter example! Does this mean then that the statement is false ? Or should there be another way to prove that $\beta'$ is continuous ? Or  maybe that $g:= f' \circ f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: I was about to say that, yes, this means the statement is false. You can make your curve $\alpha$ to be the interval $(f(-1), f(1))$ with the identity parametrization, now $\beta=\alpha\circ f$ is not $C^1$. Somehow defining a curve to be $C^1$ but allowing differentiable reparametrization don't go together. Either everything is $C^1$ or everything is just differentiable. I think $C^1$ is the standard choice, for a lot of purposes.